# Knex: why does not the call "create table" perform without next call of "then"

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm, knex.js

I faced with the next problem. If I am trying to create table, calling these methods - there is not result:

```
    this.knexDB.schema
        .createTable("students", table => {
            table.increments("id");
            table.string("student_name");
            table.string("studnt_number");
        });
```

The table does not create.
However if I add the call of "then" - the table creates right away:

```
    this.knexDB.schema
        .createTable("students", table => {
            table.increments("id");
            table.string("student_name");
            table.string("studnt_number");
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("table created!");
        });
```

---

**Questions**:

1. Why does it work like this?
2. Are there any ways to call `create table` right away using more "appropriate" way?

Comment: Your actual code must be doing something else. As shown there is no difference as to whether the table is created or not - perhaps it's code that is trying to use the table that is being performed inside the .then in the second case (where it will work) as opposed to however you're trying to use it in the first case - but rest assured, the two pieces of code you've presented are effectively identical

Comment: @JaromandaX, code just creates table. You can see it in the method `createTableIfNotExists` on the [GitHub Repo of this project](https://github.com/RostislavDugin/CRUD-Application/blob/master/js/database.js)

Comment: in that case the tables are created - you've followed the knex.js documentation correctly, and the problem you are seeing is due to something else you haven't considered

Comment: @JaromandaX, at once I've seen the same problem somewhere in Knex's Gihub Repo, but I can't find it again. This problem reproduces with other people... As for me - it doesn't cause problems, but I've just interested in the reasons of this case... Even if it appears only for me (however, the project is quite small and clear, I don't know what can affect it. Moreover, in documentation `then` uses too, but without describing why).

Comment: .then is used to *wait* for the tables to be created before using them - that's how promises work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Knex` is a query builder lib, it has chaineable api that allows you to chaine different method invokes to construct the query.

As of the fact that db querying is an async operation by fact, the lib author decided to "invoke" db querying on calling a pseudo promise like api. Therefore there is a need to call `then`.

If you are using `async` & `await` you can use it, the `wait` will invoke `then` implicitly.

```
await this.knexDB.schema.createTable('students', table => {
  table.increments('id');
  table.string('student_name');
  table.string('studnt_number');
});
```